# Find the variance of a log-likelihood function in item response theory

Tags: probability, variance, log-likelihood

I am trying to derive the variance of a log-likelihood function based on a dichotomous item response theory model.

The log-likelihood function is as follows:

$$l_o = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\log{P_i(\theta)} + (1-x_i)\log{[1-P_i(\theta)]}$$

where $X_i=\left\{
       \begin{array}{lr}
        1 & \text{if the response to item } i \text{ is correct}\\
        0 & \text{if the response to item } i \text{ is incorrect}\\
        \end{array}
        \right. $

and $P_i(\theta)$ is the probability of correct response given $\theta$  (i.e., $P(X_i=1|\theta)$.

I wanted to obtain $E(l_0)$ and $Var(l_0)$. I was able to get $E(l_0)$ as

$$l_o = \sum_{i=1}^nP_i(\theta)\log{P_i(\theta)} + (1-P_i(\theta))\log{[1-P_i(\theta)]}$$

by basically replacing $x_i$ with its expected value $P_i(\theta)$ and $1-x_i$ with $(1-P_i(\theta)).$

But I could not derive $Var(l_0)$. I tried to do it by following $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)^2]$ but I am lost in all those algebra (and I am not sure following the variance-expectation formula is the best way to go).

I know the end result should be

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(l_{0}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}(\theta)\left(1-p_{i}(\theta)\right)\left\{\ln \left[\frac{p_{i}(\theta)}{1-p_{i}(\theta)}\right]\right\}^{2}$$.

Could anyone help me how I could derive to the end result? Thank you so much!!!